# How to make floating button in flutter stay at the navigation

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm newbie in the flutter, and when I create a floating button in the navigation bar to show the record form. But when I try to input something to the textfield, the floating button not stay in the bottom (navigation bar)

floating button in the navigation bar

[image]

after input something to the textfields

[image]

Anyone can help me how to fix this? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, your Scaffold has been instructed to resize itself whenever a keyboard opens up.

This is controlled by the `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` property of the `Scaffold`.

When you set it to false, your `Scaffold` won't resize itself when a Keyboard is open causing your `Scaffold` to still take up the entire device height behind the Keyboard.

Use it like this,

```
 Scaffold(
   resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false
```